# Python: Compare two values in pandas dataframe and get index of minimum value

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe:

```
In [11]: dframe = pd.DataFrame({"A":list("abcde"), "B":list("fghij"), "C":[1,2,3,4,5]},  index=[10,11,12,13,14])

Out[11]:
    A   B   C
10  a   f   1
11  b   g   2
12  c   h   3
13  d   i   4
14  e   j   5
```

Question: Compare values in 'C' column of first (1) and second (2) row and get index of minimum?  
Answer: 10

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your question. What would the expected result be here? You only want to do a comparison of the first two rows, and only in column C? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to explain properly :( I want to compare the value 1 and 2 in the column 'C' and get the index of the minimum (answer: 10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dframe[0:2]['C'].idxmin()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Good point, just copied&pasted from shell, fixed it now!

Comment: @Thanos, yeah I deleted my comment and gave you a +1 after you made the edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevad, I need to wait 8 minutes to accept after answering.

Comment: One more thing, @Thanos, and this is more so an explicit vs. implicit or stylistic, but some users may prefer to use `df.iloc[slice]` rather than `df[slice]`, even though both equate to the same thing. Doesn't change anything on the correctness of the answer, and both have the same performance.

This is mainly since chain indexing can sometimes be unreliable, especially with hierarchical headers, or when the slice or column is defined programmatically.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#slicing-ranges

Comment: @Thanos, if I want to compare first and third row, instead first and second row?

Comment: @ramesh, `iloc` and dataframe slices accept either a list, a slice, or an integer. Just pass `dframe.iloc[[1, 3]]` instead of `dframe.iloc[:2]`.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: Thanks !

Comment: @ramesh, for a full guide on how to slice and index dataframes, check the link I posted above (also included here). It's a comprehensive guide to Pandas slicing and indexing operations.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#slicing-ranges